# Does URL Shorter Effect My SEO Endeavor?

Tags: url, seo

Hope this post will not be  killed on the ground of "NOT PROGRAMMING RELATED".

It seems everyone is flocking to URL shorten service recently. For some special sites like twitter, I am really OK with it.

However, I just wandering if I use that shorten URL in other place like PR, am I losing back links juicy? or are there any other down sides that I need to bear by using the shorten URL?

Many thanks to those who are enjoying closing posts for sparing my question!

Best regards to those who are reading, considering and answering my question!

Good holidays!

Comment: Don't close this as not programming related.  It is an issue that most of us web developers do have to deal with at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely are losing SEO value.  But yes, this isn't the best place to ask this question.  I don't know where to send you, but maybe webmasterworld or something.  They have forums.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a little bit.  You're sending traffic to the URL shortener first (and link juice) but then you get free click-through statistics (as with bit.ly) and, of course, the shortening effect.

If you don't *need* a shortener, make the links full.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The biggest question you have to ask yourself if you rely on an URL shortener that you don't run yourself: Who *exactly* are you relying on for working links into your web site?